# Google Analytics to Cache Location Data for Users Accessing via Known Proxy

Tags: google-analytics, proxy, intranet

I have a website hosted on an internal work network, which is exclusively accessed through a proxy. Since all of the requests are being routed through the proxy, the location data is singular. Specific location data is primarily what I'm interested in aggregating.

Is there a way to drill down to get more refined location data with GA?

Is there a better alternative for location based tracking of requests?

Is this fundamentally the point of a proxy, and is there no possible way for me to get the data I want?

Answer (score 0):

### Pass users IP adress as a parameter

The geolocation data are derrived from IP adress.

**Your server will extrend each hit by:**

```
&uip=192.21.0.11    // IP address
&ua=Opera/9.80  // User agent
```

**Or you can do it in JavaScript:**

ga('set', '&uip', '192.21.0.11');
ga('set', '&ua', 'Opera/9.80');

Comment: okay -- but how do I know my user's ip address? I only know the proxy they are accessing through.

Comment: Your proxy server have to extend this query string. If not, IP adress information is lost. Parameter uip is here specially for this purpose.